Flutter firebase auth gives error "The provider has already been linked to the user"
I have implemented firebase auth with google and twitter. Now first time when I do login with twitter with my email id - hello@example.com then the sign in is successful and I am able to see my email and twitter icon in firebase auth.
Now after that when I do signin with google with same email id - hello@example.com then it is replaced with google icon in firebase auth.
Now when I try to login again with twitter with same email id - hello@example.com then it throws an error The provider has already been linked to the user.
I have enabled "Link accounts that use the same email" option in setting.
I am following their official doc
How do I allow user to login with same email id with different provider?

My guess is that where you say hello@example.com, you're actually using <something>@gmail.com or a similar domain that is hosted by Google/gmail.
Firebase Authentication has the concept of a preferred provider for certain email domains, and Google Authentication is the preferred provider for @gmail.com addresses. That explains why the sign-in with Google takes over the Twitter sign-in you did before: the Google Authentication provider can actually internally prove that it owns/hosts that email address, while Twitter cannot.
If you want to use multiple providers to sign-in to the same account, you should link those accounts together, which is a separate flow. Just checking the ""Link accounts that use the same email" option the Firebase console does not automatically do that for you.

Yes. I have email with @gmail.com for both twitter and google. I did try that separate flow but seems getting same error instead of link account.

I'm not sure what you mean by that last bit, and have a feeling that more words are not going to help there. The first two paragraphs of my answer explain the behavior you have, the last paragraph links to the approach you should use to be able to use multiple sign-in providers with a single account. If you can't get that to work, I recommend opening a new question with (just) a minimal repro (read the link please, it's quite useful).

I understood your answer but my point is that when I tried to link account with that doc ref. It shows the same error that "Link accounts that use the same email"

If the explanation and link in my answer were clear, led to a change in the approach in your code, and you're having a hard time making that new approach work - it is a new problem and needs a new post with a minimal repro. --- Also see What should I do when someone answers my question?

Ok. Sure. Let me try your approach.
